# Meteor: mdg:camera package fails

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, meteor, camera

I do:

```
MeteorCamera.getPicture({
            quality : 85
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                Session.set("photoUri", data);
            }
        });
```

If I run Meteor locally and access localhost:3000, everything works as expected.

If, however, I test this on a meteor.com deployment....

In Chrome, I see a dialog box:

```
Camera Permissions Denied
You have denied this app permission to use your camera. If you would like to allow permissions, follow the directions for your browser below.

Google Chrome
Go to Settings > "Show advanced settings..." > "Content settings..." >    Media heading > "Manage exceptions...", then find this website in the list and allow video capture.

Mozilla Firefox
Reload the page and try again.

Opera
Go to Preferences > Websites > Media heading > "Manage exceptions...", then find this website in the list and allow video capture.
```

I did find the "exceptions" setting in question (in a different place than described), but there appears to be no way to edit this list....

So, I tried in Firefox, where I simply see:

```
There was an error accessing the camera.
```

Neither Chrome not Firefox pass any error to the callback function.

This behavior is the same on the desktop and in a browser on an Android device.

Answer (score 1):

From the console in chrome:

```
getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details
```

Outside of localhost, you'll have to be running a secure site (https) for it to work properly.

Try this to prove out the above:
http://cheese-test.meteor.com/ 
vs
https://cheese-test.meteor.com/